# Convert html to word document using docx4j in java

Tags: java, html, ms-word, docx4j

> I am converting HTML Document into word document using Docx4j jar.
>   finally i got the word document but i could not change the default
>   properties. I have facing the following problems in Docx4j jar

How to set the custom page size of document using Docx4j properties other than default page size A4,A3, B4JIS?

Comment: Please edit your question and split it into 2 separate questions.  Make the second one about font family only (ie remove 'all other properties').

Comment: are you asking for a library or are you requesting help with your code?

Comment: this question still contains 2 completely different issues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor

```
XHTMLImporterImpl(WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage)
```

specifies the docx into which your content will be imported.  (I assume you're doing it that way; if you are using altChunk, what follows would still apply, unless Word adds a sectPr!)

It takes on the page size defined in that docx.

[Page size is defined in the sectPr element](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/Sections.html), so more precisely, it takes on the page size of the applicable sectPr.

So, you can either change that, or add a new sectPr.  Note: since a sectPr applies to the content before it, you should add a sectPr with the existing sectPr properties (or move the existing one), then your content, then a sectPr with the page size you want.

To generate relevant code, use the docx4j code generation tool, available via the [docx4j webapp](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/PartsList.html), or the [code gen Word AddIn](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2014/12/docx4jhelper-word-addin/).

Comment: Thanks for  your answer. Please see my code [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356235/how-to-set-font-size-and-font-family-in-word-document-using-docx4j/27356387#27356387). In this code shall i set the font size or family? i am new to this so i have no clear idea about this.

Comment: one more issue i have piece of code in HTML <img src="E:/HtmlToDoc/LOGO.JPEG"/> In my location machine logo image is embedded in Word document but in Server machine image is not  embedded in word pls help me...

Comment: Again, you should ask this new/different question as a new question.