# How to set Font size and font family in document using docx4j

Tags: html, docx4j

```
FileReader fr=new FileReader("E://HtmlToDoc//LETTER.html" );
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr); 
while( (s=br.readLine())!= null ){
    html=html+s;}

html="<html><body>"+html.substring(html.indexOf("<body>"));

/************************ Setting Page Size   **********************************/
Docx4jProperties.getProperties().setProperty("docx4j.PageSize", "B4JIS");
String papersize= Docx4jProperties.getProperties().getProperty("docx4j.PageSize", "B4JIS");

String landscapeString = Docx4jProperties.getProperties().getProperty("docx4j.PageOrientationLandscape", "true");
boolean landscape= Boolean.parseBoolean(landscapeString);

WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage(PageSizePaper.valueOf(papersize), landscape);

AlternativeFormatInputPart afiPart = new AlternativeFormatInputPart(new PartName("/hw.html"));
afiPart.setBinaryData(html.getBytes());
//afiPart.setBinaryData(fileContent);

afiPart.setContentType(new ContentType("text/html"));
Relationship altChunkRel = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(afiPart);

// .. the bit in document body
CTAltChunk ac = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTAltChunk();
ac.setId(altChunkRel.getId() );
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(ac);

// .. content type
wordMLPackage.getContentTypeManager().addDefaultContentType("html", "text/html");
wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("E://HtmlToDoc//" + "test.docx"));
```

This is my code converts from HTML to Word document. How to set font size and font family for this word document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pulling HTML content in to a Word document as a collection of `AltChunk` instances, which means the HTML exists in the docx 'bundle' as separate file, and not as part of the flow of the actual Word document.

If you want to manipulate the imported content as native MS Word content, you need to import the source XHTML instead. This means that docx4j takes the mark-up and (some) related styles, converting them into the various constituent parts of a docx file (for example, table, text, run and paragraph elements). Once you have content imported in that way, you can style it as you would any other docx entities.